# Diploma in English?

Tags: single-word-requests

I must refer to my High School Diploma (Italy), how is it known abroad?

I mean, can I simply write High School Diploma?

In UK or USA, how is such a qualification recognized as?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. Are you asking whether an employer/university here (US) would recognize your High School Diploma as valid? I don't quite understand "how is it known abroad." And what or whom are you referring your diploma to? Maybe its my fault, just lost...

Comment: awesome... :) I think Noldorin's answer is good; although I have no knowledge of UK policy

Comment: Exam certificates don't automatically map across international boundaries. A driving licence / drivers licence in one country may not necessarily be acceptable in another country. Having essentially the same name does not mean that diplomas etc automatically carry the same weight. / You should write '(Italian) High School Diploma', but investigate how it's perceived by the host country. But this is not germane on ELU.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially asking how foreign qualifications are perceived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, in the US, "high school diploma" is exactly the right term, and will be understood anywhere you go.

Here in the UK, I'm afraid we don't really have an equivalent; the only papers we get upon leaving are the examiners certificates for our GCSE/A-level exams - not exactly "diplomas". Saying that, I'm sure most Brits would at least *recognise* the significance of a "high school diploma" from a continental European country.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good point by Noldorin but, it needs some clarification.

Yes, in the UK, there isn't an equivalent to "High School Diploma". The UK does not have the American, "High School" system. It generally has GCSEs. These are the exams that people do at school. There is at least, one exam in each subject. Some subjects, have more.

A-level exams are something else. They are exams that are done in sixth form, something that is done after, leaving school and. Sixth form is a second stage between school and university. It is not compulsory and therefore, it is not school. It is however, necessary for people who want to go to university. A-levels are normally a pre-condition for going to university.

If there is not an equivalent to A-levels and sixth form in Italy, the equivalent to a "High School Diploma", would be GCSEs.

If your main point is to refer to exams that people do at the end of their time at school, generally (whatever state they are from); you can call them school exams. This will be a sufficient description for any such exams, anywhere.

For your case Andry, you can describe it like this. In the general sense, you can say that you have a school exam/school exams (depending on if you did one or, more than one). In the specific sense, you can say that you have a "High School Diploma". Therefore, you can say to non-Italians "I have a school exam. A High School Diploma."

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_school) describes the American system well -- a High School diploma is broadly equivalent to A-level. It indicates that Italy doesn't actually have a High School system, so if Andry's qualification is awarded around age 18-19, before going to university, it's equivalent to the American High School diploma.

Comment: Andrew. It seems that clarification of this, is needed. If you are right, the equivalent in the UK, will depend on the age at which the Italian "High School Diploma", is awarded.

Comment: Exactly so. We have no idea what the OP meant by "High School diploma", although it's a reasonable guess that he intended it in the American way.

Answer (score 0):

When translating foreign educational certificates, one can provide the specific certificate that was earned (with perhaps a literal translation in parenthesis), and also an explanation of what that would be equivalent to in the educational system of the country where the translation will be presented.